# Destroy component from service Angular

Tags: angular

Is it possible to destroy component from serivce? For example call this.component.ngOnDestroy() in service method or something similar?

Comment: You can actually manually create and destroy components using [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) if that fits your case

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that, it's a lifecycle hook that is called when angular destroys the component by itself.

You can use the `ngIf` directive in the component and update the value in the directive using service. This is the way you can remove the angular component from DOM and angular destroys it automatically.